# Firebase C++ Cloud Messaging background issues

Tags: android, c++, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, I have a Firebase C++ SDK integrated into my Android app and I'm having certain troubles handling my push notifications when my app is in the background.

The thing is that for some reason **OnMessage** method of **messaging::Listener** class never gets called when I launch my app through a notification, which is weird, because in a situation when my app is already in foreground when the device gets a notification - **OnMessage** gets called perfectly fine and I get all the info about the received notification.

AFAIK **OnMessage** should also be called by the Firebase sdk when a user launches/resumes the app through the notification from the notification bar so that the app could get the payload, but this doesn't happen for me for some reason and I don't know where to look (nothing in adb log, no errors, etc).

Comment: Hi. Depending on the message payload, you might be just experiencing the expected behavior (see [Handling Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)). Could you post a sample payload you're sending?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that Firebase Cloud Messaging C++ SDK for Android requires some additional coding that is not described in the integration documentation, but, can be found in the sample app on Github (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/blob/master/messaging/testapp/src/android/java/com/google/firebase/example/TestappNativeActivity.java#L35).

When I added the missing code in **onNewIntent** method - FCM **OnMessage** callback started to work as expected;